# how to implement linked list that can accept any type upon which equality testing can be done in golang?

Tags: interface, go

I'm trying to implement a linked list in golang. And I want the linked list to be able to store any type upon which equality testing can be performed.

Like say if there is,

```
type SimpleType struct {
    int
}
s := SimpleType{3}
m := SimpleType{4}
```

I want to be able to do something like,

`if s == m {}` or `if s < m` and other equality testing.

I know I can accomplish this using interfaces. Like say, I can create an interface that has a comparison function and make the linked list only accept values that have the interface type.

But I was wondering if there was a better, more idiomatic way of doing it in Golang.

Like say, is it possible to directly use the relational operators `<`, `>`, `==` and co?

Or if that is not possible, is there a much better way using interfaces itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should combine [`container/list`](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/) with ideas from [`sort.Interface`](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface).

Basically, in your package `mylist` you'd define something like:

```
type ListItem struct {
    ...
}

type Interface interface {
    func Less(a, b *ListItem) bool
    func Equal(a, b *ListItem) bool
}
```

(`func Greater(a, b *ListItem) bool` is not needed because it's just `!Less(a, b)`; same applies to `NotEqual()`)
…and then implement sorting function on your list which would require the caller to provide an implementation of `Interface` to use by your algorythm—just like `sort.Sort()` does.

To implement that you'd define

```
func Sort(head *ListElement, comp Interface) *ListElement
```

which would take the list's head, sort it using the provided comparator and return the head of the sorted list.
The client would be required to provide a comparator, like with

```
import "github.com/Jay/mylist"
...
type Foo struct {
    ...
    Id int // used for comparisons
    ...
}

type FooComp struct{}

func (FooComp) Less(a, b *mylist.ListItem) bool {
    fa, fb := a.Value().(Foo), b.Value().(Foo)
    return fa.Id < fb.Id
}

func (FooComp) Equal(a, b *mylist.ListItem) bool {
    fa, fb := a.Value().(Foo), b.Value().(Foo)
    return fa.Id == fb.Id
}

data := mylist.New()
head := mylist.PushBack(Foo{...})
// ... add more elements here

// Now sort the list using the comparator
head := mylist.Sort(head, FooComp{})
```

Here, the client code defines its own type, `Foo`, to be stored in your list, and a comparator for it, `FooComp` to be used for sorting by your implementation.